# How to make one item follow the movement of another in QML?

Tags: qml

I have mutiple items in one window, all of which can be dragged in the area. How could it be possible to make other items "follow" the dragged item?[image]
Thanks!

Comment: How does the code look? Based on that, we can come up with adjusted code

Answer (score 1):

### Just set a binding between x and y properties.

A small example:
*(change x and y corresponding to your needs)*

```
import QtQuick 2.12

Item {
    anchors.fill: parent
   Rectangle{id: _dragged

        color: "red"
       width: 50;
       height: width
       DragHandler{}
   }
  Rectangle{
        x: _dragged.x - 100
        y: _dragged.y
        color: "red"
       width: 50;
       height: width
   }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this solution does not apply to my application. The items in my application are pretty indepedent. It is just in some cases that some items (dynamically determined) need to be bound and move sychronously.

Comment: In that case ig  you can use states and transitions https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-tutorial3.html then set a flag in your dragged element that turns on when its dragged..

Answer (score 1):

After days of trying, I found a way works for me.

```
import QtQuick 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls 1.1
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

Rectangle {
    id: win
    width: 800
    height: 600
    color: "gainsboro"
    visible: true


    Rectangle {
        id: rect1
        width: 50
        height: 50
        z: mouseArea1.drag.active ||  mouseArea1.pressed ? 2 : 1
        color: "blue"
        x: 50
        y: 100
        border { width:2; color: "white" }
        radius: 5
        Drag.active: mouseArea1.drag.active
        Drag.supportedActions: Qt.CopyAction
        property point beginDrag

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "tile1"
            color: "white"
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea1
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent

            onPressed:  {
                rect1.beginDrag = Qt.point(rect1.x, rect1.y)
                rect2.beginDrag = Qt.point(rect2.x, rect2.y)
            }

            onPositionChanged: {
                var delta_x = rect1.x - rect1.beginDrag.x
                var delta_y = rect1.y - rect1.beginDrag.y
                rect2.x = rect2.beginDrag.x + delta_x
                rect2.y = rect2.beginDrag.y + delta_y
            }
        }
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rect2
        width: 50
        height: 50
        z: mouseArea2.drag.active ||  mouseArea2.pressed ? 2 : 1
        color: "cyan"
        x: 200
        y: 100
        property point beginDrag
        property bool caught: false

        border { width:2; color: "white" }
        radius: 5
        Drag.active: mouseArea2.drag.active
        Drag.supportedActions: Qt.CopyAction

        Text {
            anchors.centerIn: parent
            text: "tile2"
            color: "green"
        }
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea2
            anchors.fill: parent
            drag.target: parent
        }
    }

    DropArea{
        id: dropArea
        anchors.fill: parent
    }
}
```

I hope this can help and expect more elegant implementation.